# Bash nested if fails

Tags: bash

I am trying to do a while loop that iterates 10 times to retry 2 consecutive commands;

Basically;

```
retries=10
  while ((retries > 0)); do
    if ! command; then
      if ! other_command; then
                 echo "Failed to start service - retrying ${retries}"
         else
             echo "Started service successfully"
             break
          fi
         fi
         ((retries --))
         if ((retries == 0 )); then
             echo "service failed to start!"
         fi
     done
```

But I cannot seem to nest it properly to get the desired result, which is;
try one command, if it fails, try second command. Try these 2 commands, one after the  other 10 times.
If either command is successful at any time, break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to nest the ifs, `break` helps to avoid it. It basically follows what you described.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
retries=10
while ((retries)) ; do
    if command1 ; then
        break
    elif command2 ; then
        break
    fi
    ((--retries))
done

if ((!retries)) ; then
    echo 'Service failed to start!' >&2
fi
```

Tested with both commands defined as

```
command1 () {
    r=$((RANDOM%10))
    if ((r)) ; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
```